Seeking Analytical Solution for Constrained Optimization Problem with Multiple Variables
I am struggling to solve the following optimization problem
\begin{aligned} \min_{\{u_{1},u_{2},u_{3}\}} & \quad10u_{1}+15u_{2}+5u_{3} \\ \text{s.t.} \quad & \frac{1}{u_{1}}+\frac{1}{u_{2}}+ \frac{1}{u_{3}}= 16 
\\ & 0\leq u_{1}\leq \frac{1}{5} ,\;\;0\leq u_{2}\leq \frac{1}{3},\;\;0\leq u_{3}\leq \frac{1}{7}
\end{aligned}
which is equivalent to
\begin{aligned} \min_{\{u_{1},u_{2},u_{3}\}} & \quad10u_{1}+15u_{2}+5u_{3} \\ \text{s.t.} \quad & u_{2}u_{3}+u_{1}u_{3}+u_{1}u_{2}= 16 u_{1}u_{2}u_{3} 
\\ & 0\leq 5u_{1}\leq 1 ,\;\;0\leq 3u_{2}\leq 1,\;\;0\leq 7u_{3}\leq 1
\end{aligned}
How can I solve this problem analytically, and what is the type of this optimization problem?

Hint. Transform the problem by using variables $x_i = 1/u_i$, then the equality contraint becomes linear but the objective is still convex.

@p.s., thanks. I tried that already, but it did not lead to an analytical solution.

Using Mathematica - a Computer Algebra System (CAS), you can obtain the solution: The minimum is $\frac{181}{28}$ when $u_1 = 1/5, u_2 = 1/4, u_3 = 1/7$. We can prove this without calculus, or using calculus.

@RiverLi, thank you. Yes, I use Maple, but I want to know the analytical solution for such a problem if it does exist.

@WirelessEngineer For this specific problem, there is surely an analytical solution. It depends on what solution do you want. Can we use the information that Mathematica/Maple tells us? Based on this information, we can prove (by hand) that the minimum is $181/28$ where $u_1 = 1/5, u_2 = 1/4, u_3 = 1/7$.

@WirelessEngineer I am curious what do you mean an analytical solution?
